# Python: Serializing/de-serializing huge amount of data

Tags: python, serialization

I have a (very large) dataset. Something in the order of 250,000 binary vectors, each of size 800.
The dataset resides in a (.txt ascii coding) file, in 'compressed representation'. Meaning, every line in that file represents how a vector looks, rather than 800 characters of zeroes and ones.
For example, suppose that the i'th line in that file looks like this:

```
12 14 16 33 93 123 456 133
```

This means that the i'th vector is a vector with its 12'th 14'th, 16'th, ... 133'th indices holding the value 1, and the rest are zeroes.

The file's size is a little more than 30MB.

Now, since I use this data to feed a neural network, this data need some preprocessing, in order to transform it into what the network expects: list of size 250,000, where every element in that list is a 20x40 matrix (list of lists) of zeros and ones.
For example, if we rescale the problem to 4x2, this is what the final list looks like:

```
[[[1,0],[1,1],[0,0],[1,0]], [[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,0]], ..., [[1,1],[0,1],[0,0],[1,1]]]
```

(only instead of 4x2 I have 20x40 matrices).

So I wrote two functions:  `load_data()` - which parses the file and returns a list of 800 binary lists, and `reshape()` - which reshapes the lists to a 20x40 matrices.
Needless to say that my poor laptop works really hard when `load_data()` and `reshape()` are running. It takes about 7-9 minutes to complete the preprocessing, while in that time I can barley do anything else in my laptop. Even minimizing the IDE window is an extremely difficult task.
Since I use this data to adjust a neural net, I find myself very often killing the running process, re-tuning the network, and starting again - where every restart results with an invoke to `load_data()` followed by `reshape()`.
So, I decided to short-cut through this painful process of loading the data --> transforming to binary vectors --> reshaping it.
I want to load the data from the file, transform to binary vectors, reshaping it and serializing it to a file `my_input`.
Now, whenever I need to feed the network, I can just de-serialize the data from `my_input`, and spare me a lot of time.
This is how I did it:

```
input_file=open('my_input', 'wb')

print 'loading data from file...'
input_data=load_data()  # this will load the data from file and will re-encode it to binary vectors

print 'reshaping...'
reshaped_input=reshape(input_data)

print 'writing to file...'
cPickle.dump(reshaped_input, input_file, HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
input_file.close()
```

The problem is this:
The resulting file is huge; 1.7GB in size, and it seems like the game is not worth the candle (I hope I used it right), since it takes too much time to load it (didn't measure how much, I just tried to load it, and after 9-10 minutes I gave up and killed the process).

Why is the resulting file is so much bigger than the original (I'd expect it to be bigger, but not by that much)?
Is there another way to encode the data (serialize/de-serialize wise), that will result in a smaller file, and will worth my while?
Or, alternatively, if anyone can suggest a better way to speed things up (besides buying a faster computer) that would also be great.

p.s I don't care about compatibility issues when it comes to de-serializing. The only place where this data will ever be de-serialized is on my computer.

Comment: Have you tried numpy.save? There are versions which include compression too.. http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.save.html

Comment: Although not related to your question... if you have an `800` dimensions feature vector and "only" `250000` samples, then do not forget to try to perform dimensionality reduction on the training set before feeding the data to your neural network! (if you are not already doing that, of course) ;-)

Comment: @bsa, numpy.save does what cPickle.dump does, in terms of results. I get the same file from using either.

Comment: Check out Sparse matrices:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were to store a bit for each value in your data, you'd end up with a 25MB file; so your "compression" scheme is actually making your file bigger. The only advantage of your current scheme is that you get to store your data in ascii.

Calculation:

```
250.000 * 800 bits = 250.000 * 100 bytes = 25.000.000 bytes = 25 MB
```

So just store the bit patterns manually, read them back in and go on with your calculations.

**Edit:** Looks like the path of least resistance is to use the third-party module [`packbits`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/packbits/) (i.e. you need to download it). You must first flatten your long list of matrices into a flat list on the fly (as an iterator), write it out as a sequence of bits (note: every 32-bit int can be "packed" with 32 values-- not just one value as you suggest in the comments), then do the reverse conversion on input. List-flattening recipes are a dime a dozen (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/952914/699305) for a selection), but here's one with complementary unflattening code.

```
from itertools import zip_longest    
def chunks(iterable, size):
    "chunks(3, 'abcdefg', 'x') --> ('a','b','c'), ('d','e','f'), ('g', 0, 0)"
    return zip_longest(*[iter(iterable)]*size, fillvalue=0)

def flatten(data):
    """Convert a list of N x M matrices into a flat iterator"""
    return ( v for matrix in data for row in matrix for v in row )

def unflatten(data, n, m):
    """Convert a flat sequence (of ints) into a list of `n` by `m` matrices"""
    msize = n * m
    for chunk in chunks(data, msize):
        yield [ chunk[i:i+m] for i in range(0, msize, m) ]
```

If `sampledata` is your sample array of 4 x 2 matrices,

```
rt = list(unflatten(flatten(sampledata), 4, 2))
```

is a list with the same structure and values (but tuples instead of row arrays). Can you fill in the rest?

Comment: It's the 'reading them back' that I'm concerned about. If I'm to save them as bits, this means that again the data would have to be transformed to what the network expects; list of lists of lists of ints (zeroes and ones) whenever the data is loaded from the 25MB file. Every bit needs to be transformed to four bytes' integer representing zero, or one.

Comment: Fair enough. Let me mull it over and see how easy it would be to write some code to round-trip the data. But why _are_ you using lists and not numpy arrays?

Comment: Because they are is easier to work, at least for me. I do convert all of the lists to arrays with numpy.asarray before serializing though (before reshape() that is... lists don't have reshape()).

Comment: Do you convert to numpy just to flatten your lists? You don't need to-- included it in my answer.

Comment: Be sure to pack your data so that you're using all bits in your ints-- not one value per int, as you suggested in your comment above. Otherwise your file will be 32 times bigger, and you'll _probably_ need more time to read and write it than it would take to unpack the bits.